# Displaying image causes styling error? React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm getting this strange Sass error in React and I don't understand how it is related to my styles.

This is an example of how my styles are set up:

```
_colours.scss
$red: red;
```

```
_baseStyles.scss
.wrapper {
   border: 1px solid $red;
}
```

```
App.scss
@import "./styles/colours";
@import "./styles/baseStyles";
```

So far everything works fine, no issues. Then I mapped over an array of objects that I'm displaying to the page. I have an image, but it does not show up unless i use the 'require' keyword like this:

```
<img src={require(`${user.image.png}`)} alt={`Portrait of ${user.username}`}/>
```

Then all of a sudden, I get this error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
  ╷
6 │   border: 1px solid $red;
  │                     ^^^^
  ╵
```

If i remove the 'require' on the src then the error disappears, but my image does not show up. How is the 'require' related to my styles?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try @use instead of @import**

You can check this site for more info :
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

```css
_baseStyles.scss

@use "./colours";

.wrapper {
   border: 1px solid colours.$red;
}
```

or

```css
_baseStyles.scss

@use "./colours" as *;
.wrapper {
   border: 1px solid $red;
}
```